# Manual release of fuel door on 1998 VW Beetle

Tags: beetle, fuel-cap

My daughter bought a ‘98 Beetle as a project car. The previous owner cut a number of wires and portions of the chassis electrical system don’t work, like the fuel door release and the power windows. While we hunt down the cut wires or whatever is keeping this from working, is there a way to manually release the fuel door?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There may be one directly on the inside of the car respective to the gas cap. Many cars have this; yours may be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a plastic access panel in the boot (or "trunk" if you're in the US) near the rear light cluster behind where the fuel filler door is, pop that off and you should be able to see the cable and you can pull that down and it should release the catch and open the door.

Alternatively you can use a credit card to wedge in where the catch is and release it that way but tbh it's fiddly to do that way - pulling the cable is much quicker and easier IMO.